# How to add both TexTheme and DarkTheme?

Tags: flutter, dart

Right now I have this piece of code:

```
return MaterialApp(
      theme: darkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
```

But I want to add also TextTheme which before I was applying like this:

```
return MateriaApp(
       theme: themeData)

ThemeData themeData = ThemeData(
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    bodyText1: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
    bodyText2: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
  ).apply(
    bodyColor: Colors.grey[500],
  ),
);
```

If someone knew how to use both of it in the same time, thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var theme = darkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light();
theme = theme.copyWith(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
        bodyText1: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
        bodyText2: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
        ).apply(
        bodyColor: Colors.grey[500],
    ),
);

// ...
return MaterialApp(theme: theme);
```

Also, I should mention, that `MaterialApp` has a darkTheme argument. So you could write code like this:

```
return MaterialApp(theme: myLightTheme, darkTheme: myDarkTheme);
```